# drawLine() method not drawing anything

Tags: java, swing, line

So I have this class inside a class which is an implementation of JPanel.

```
    private static class Line extends JComponent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("Pozvan paintComponent()");
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.drawLine(20, 20, 100, 20);
        super.paintComponent(g);
    } 
    }
```

This is a snippet of code which creates a single instance of Line:

```
        Line line = new Line();
        line.setOpaque(true);
        add(line);
```

I really don't know what I am doing wrong here. When I draw a rectangle, everything is nicely drawn.

Comment: whats happens in the case that `super.paintComponent(g);` is 1st code line inside `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {`

Comment: Also check width/height to be sure the Line component is not 0 sized

Comment: agree with Stas, for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable, because size of JComponent can be 0

Comment: I added `line.setBounds(20, 20, 80, 50);` in that snippet of code (latter one I posted). Line was drawn on the screen, but I have absolutely no idea why it is drawn, only when I set the height to remotely big number it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I set the height to remotely big number it works.

The default size of a Swing component is (0, 0). Since the size is 0, there is nothing to paint.

```
g.drawLine(20, 20, 100, 20);
```

Using the above information this means your component needs a size of (120, 40). That is, width = 20 + 100 and height = 20 + 20, in order for the component to be painted.

```
I added line.setBounds(20, 20, 80, 50);
```

Only part of your line will be painted, since you set the width to 80, not 120.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and examples.